How to calculate the pressure of the system with molecular dynamics simulation
Suppose there are two different types of gas molecules, filling up a sealed container. Then, relax the gas system in this sealed container under -30 degree centigrade. After the full relaxation, how to calculate the pressure of gas in the container under -30 degree centigrade? Is it possible to do the pressure statistic with molecular dynamic simulation; such as LAMMPS?
Would anyone please give me some suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

You can write it to the log file with the thermo_style command, e.g. thermo_style pxx pyy pzz . You can also get the shear components pxy ...: see https://docs.lammps.org/thermo_style.html . Or, you can compute it directly and write to a file or whatever else you want to do: see https://docs.lammps.org/compute_pressure.html . Note that, from what I can tell, full relaxation implies that you are relaxing to 0 or some other pressure already. Are you doing box-relax or npt ? In either case, you have to specify the target pressure.

@Tyler Sterling Thank you very much for your suggestions. I will refer to the link you mentioned.

If it works, let me know and I’ll write and answer so we can close the question! :)
